# Querying external database in Electron app best practice?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, electron

I'm building an Electron app that connects to an external database using [MySQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). Whenever a page, `index.html`, loads, the app needs to query and get some data.

```
async function getData() {
    //Query database and return result
}
```

Is it standard, or "normal", if I were to establish a new connection each time the page is loaded, query, destroy the connection, and return the results? Or should a single connection be passed from my `main.js` electron file and only get destroyed when the app is closed? If the latter is what I should be doing, how would I pass the connection from file to file (since there's an `index.html` file in between, and it would have to pass through that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways of doing. The way that I enjoy more is to make calls from the front to the back via [IPC](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) and manage the connection at the "back". Sounds better to me as a web developer, don't mix front code with back-end code.

To make things easier, you can make a standard set of functions to make the communications using IPC easier.